# cblas_cgemm to calculate two complex matrices multiplication

Tags: lapack

I would like to call cblas_cgemm to calculate two complex matrices multiplication. While I got problems for big size, so now I am trying to set matrix A and matrix B super simple, say, just one element. Here is my c code, and the output is really strange. Anyone could help? Many thanks in advance!!

A = 1+2i
B = 3+4i

and the result should be -5+10i

The output is like:

A matrix is:

(1.00, 2.00)

B matrix is:

(3.00, 4.00)

Product of A and B is:

(-18.75, -9.38)

This is my code screenshot

[piece1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syinP.png)  [piece2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvErd.png)

Comment: Why don't you post the code from your screenshots in your question and format it as such?

Comment: Hi guys, I changed the float into double, and cgemm into zgemm, the result is finally correct!  But still, I am curious how come float and cgemm gave me the ridiculous output... Anyone, any hints? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea is the  memory allocation for example,
if in the code below you are using `malloc` i.e. `result = (micomplex *)malloc((1 * 1) * sizeof(micomplex));`
then you will get sometimes a ridiculous output like (36893488147419103232.00, 10.00) or incorrect ( -3.00, 10.00),
however using `calloc` i.e.
 `result = (micomplex *)calloc(1 * 1, sizeof(micomplex));`
gives the correct output every time ( -5.00, 10.00), when executing the code.

In order to use the code with `double` make the following changes:
`float` to `double` and `cblas_cgemm` to `cblas_zgemm`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cblas.h>

/* Complex datatype */
struct _micomplex { float re, im; };
typedef struct _micomplex micomplex;

void print_matrix( const char* desc, int m, int n, micomplex* a, int lda );

int main()
  {

   int m=3, n=2,k=4;
   float alpha=1.0, beta=0.0;
   micomplex *result;

// result = (micomplex *)malloc((1 * 1) * sizeof(micomplex));  // gives ridiculous output (36893488147419103232.00, 10.00)
   result = (micomplex *)calloc(1 * 1, sizeof(micomplex));   // gives correct output ( -5.00, 10.00)
// the result must be (1 + 2 i) (3 + 4 i) = -5 + 10 i
   micomplex a[1*1]={{1,2}};
   micomplex b[1*1]={{3,4}};

   print_matrix( "a Matrix is: \n", 1, 1, a, 1 );
   print_matrix( "b Matrix is: \n", 1, 1, b, 1 );

   cblas_cgemm(CblasRowMajor,CblasNoTrans,CblasNoTrans,1,1,1,&alpha,a,1,b,1,&beta,result,1);
   print_matrix( "Product a and b is: \n", 1, 1, result, 1);
   free(result);

// dgemm(CblasNoTrans,CblasNoTrans,m,n,k,&alpha,A,k,B,n,&beta,result,n);
// A(mxk) B(kxn) C(mxn)

   micomplex A[3*4]={{1,1},{2,2},{-2,-2},{0,0},
                    {-3,-3},{4,4},{7,7},{2,2},
                    {6,6},{0,0},{3,3},{1,1}};

   micomplex B[4*2]={{-1,-1},{3,3},
                     {0,0},{9,9},
                     {1,1},{-11,-11},
                     {4,4},{-5,-5}};

// result = (micomplex *)malloc((m * n) * sizeof(micomplex)); // gives ridiculous output (-8589934592.00, -6.00) (-8589934592.00, 86.00)
   result = (micomplex *)calloc(m * n, sizeof(micomplex));  // gives correct output (  0.00, -6.00) (  0.00, 86.00)

   print_matrix( "A Matrix is: \n", m, k, A, k );
   print_matrix( "B Matrix is: \n", k, n, B, n );

   cblas_cgemm(CblasRowMajor,CblasNoTrans,CblasNoTrans,m,n,k,&alpha,A,k,B,n,&beta,result,n);
   print_matrix( "Product A and B is: \n", m, n, result, n);
   free(result);
   exit( 0 );
  }

void print_matrix( const char* desc, int m, int n, micomplex* a, int lda ) {
        int i, j;
        printf( "\n %s\n", desc );
        for( i = 0; i < m; i++ ) {
                for( j = 0; j < n; j++ )
                        printf( " (%6.2f,%6.2f)", a[i*lda+j].re, a[i*lda+j].im );
                printf( "\n" );
        }
}
```

the output:

```
  a Matrix is: 
  (  1.00,  2.00)

  b Matrix is: 
  (  3.00,  4.00)

  Product a and b is: 
  ( -5.00, 10.00)

  A Matrix is: 
  (  1.00,  1.00) (  2.00,  2.00) ( -2.00, -2.00) (  0.00,  0.00)
  ( -3.00, -3.00) (  4.00,  4.00) (  7.00,  7.00) (  2.00,  2.00)
  (  6.00,  6.00) (  0.00,  0.00) (  3.00,  3.00) (  1.00,  1.00)

  B Matrix is: 
  ( -1.00, -1.00) (  3.00,  3.00)
  (  0.00,  0.00) (  9.00,  9.00)
  (  1.00,  1.00) (-11.00,-11.00)
  (  4.00,  4.00) ( -5.00, -5.00)

  Product A and B is: 
  (  0.00, -6.00) (  0.00, 86.00)
  (  0.00, 36.00) (  0.00,-120.00)
  (  0.00,  2.00) (  0.00,-40.00)
```